# Which version of Catalyst AMD graphics driver will be default in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ati, radeon, 13.10, catalyst

Could it be 13.11? It is important becouse older version does not work with my graphics and Unity.

Answer (score 0):

The open source driver is default, not Catalyst/fglrx. However Catalyst is available from ubuntu software center. There it has version fglrx 2:**13.10**1-0ubuntu3, which I guess is 13.10. This is not surprising since 13.11 isn't out yet (it's in beta).